# How can i change value in decimal place with comma e.g 2,532.00 to 2532 in my table.

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

How can i change value in decimal place with comma e.g 2,532.00 to 2532 in my table. The purpose for this was that i got wrong answer whenever i sum up the column.

Please anyone to help ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the column `varchar` or a numeric type?

Comment: `cast(xxx as integer)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is a string, then you need to convert it to the appropriate type.  You can remove the comma using `replace()`:

```
select cast(replace('2,532.00', ',', '') as decimal(20, 4))
```

If you don't use `cast()` and treat the string `'2,532.00'` as a number, then MySQL does silent conversion.  That is, it converts the leading "number" characters to a number.  Because `','` is not a number character, it stops converting there and you get `2`.